# Removing overlapping part of polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, overlapping-features, delete

Here is what I'd like to achieve in QGIS.

Is there a processing tool to remove the overlapping part of polygons?

It does not matter which polygon gets clipped.

[image: Remove overlapping part of polygons]

It is also very important that they do not get merged during the process and that they keep their original attributes since I need to work with them afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the 'Check Geometries' plugin (Vector/Geometry Tools/Check Geometries) to remove overlapping areas.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This could be the solution but when I open the 'Check geometries' in QGis 2.14.3 Essen on Windows I don't get this check box that your screenshot is showing ! What am I missing ???

Comment: You have to run 'Check for overlaps smaller than (map units sqr.)'. Don't forget to enter a value, that's higher than the overlaps.

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon, I´ve the same problem, but when i execute "Check Geometries" as you said, My QGIS 2.18.8 crashes and closes. Do you have any idea why this is happening? I got a large numbers of errors, like 600 overlap errors in my data :(

Comment: @Kleber Barcelar, please open a bug report and provide your data at hub.qgis.org. Unfortunately, the geometry checker crashes quite often.

Comment: the check geometries doesnt have all this stuff ???

Comment: I have followed all of these steps and the overlapping sections don't go away. Does this tool still work in 3.4?

Comment: Where is this hidden in 3.16 or 3.22?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function *Symetrical Difference*. In QGIS: *Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools --> Symetrical Difference*.
Here is a brief overview of various tools: [Basic Editing Geoprocessing Tools in QGIS](http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis)

Now we come to your problem. A brief example:

[image]

The  function *Symetrical Difference* is started. Select a layer as *Input Layer* and another layer as *Difference Layer*. The result looks like this:

[image]
The geometries are further individual geometries and attributes have not changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I forgot to precise that gaps are to be avoid also. In the end I want one and only one polygon.

Comment: @Enzoupi The picture in your question has two polygons.