# How to remove overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, clip, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile with overlapping polygons, most overlaps are small. I want to remove all overlaps and get a new layer with similar but non overlapping polygons. 
I don't care much which of a pair of polygon gets the overlapping section. I would rather not go over them one by one. 
I've been using QGIS but am open to other tools.

[image: overlaps]

Comment: Do you need the overlap areas to belong to one of the original polygons, or can the overlap areas become their own third polygon?

Comment: Making them polygons of their own is better then what I have, but I would rather not create many sliver polygons.

Comment: Please always specify the exact version of GIS software in use and what you have tried to date.

Comment: See [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201668/how-to-remove-the-overlapping-part-of-polygons) -  check geometry  -> check for overlaps.

Comment: Thanks @NettaB .That is indeed essentially the same question(making this one a dup) and it did help some. However the check geometry only solved some of the overlaps. It failed on many claiming they do not share an edge.

Comment: Glad to help, another approach: does your data have attributes that you can dissolve the polygons with?