# Clip overlap from polygons

Tags: pyqgis, clip, overlapping-features

I am trying to script the clipping of overlapping areas from a set of polygons. After having fetched features (outerFeature) a loop (innerFeature) is to check if other features intersect with area > 0. I then try to clip the intersecting area. Apparently `difference` does not give the right result.

```
#Intersecting features
for outerFeature in pr.getFeatures():
    #Looping through all features and check if intersect
    for innerFeature in pr.getFeatures():
        geom = None
        if outerFeature.id() != innerFeature.id():
            geom = outerFeature.geometry().intersection( innerFeature.geometry() )
            #If intersection area > 0, then construct difference and update geometry
            if geom.area() > 0:
                print("intersecting and clipping")
                outerFeature.setGeometry( geom.difference( outerFeature.geometry() ) )
                vl.updateExtents()
```

Any advise is highly welcome.

Best regards

Sebastian

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this programmatically? There are QGIS tools to address this issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201668/removing-overlapping-part-of-polygons-using-qgis

Comment: The QGIS tool in mention does not allow for automated resolution to my understanding. I first want to clean programmatically and then proceed with topological editing.

Comment: The geometry checker tool should have automated resolution. See the bottom of the help file here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html

Comment: I saw that and tried it, but it did not resolve the conflicts. Suggested is to remove "Overlap with sewershed_raw at feature 31" -> Error is obsolete. This occurs for most of the several errors. When checking again they reoccur also in the same spots.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear for me what do you want to do with above code but, when you have overlapped features in the same layer you can use **itertools** python module for avoiding this kind of lines:

```
if outerFeature.id() != innerFeature.id()
```

for repeated features. So, your code can be written as follow for producing a memory layer of all intersection of primary features.

```
import itertools

layer = iface.activeLayer()

features = [ feature for feature in layer.getFeatures() ]

n = layer.featureCount()

list = range(n)

intersections = [features[i].geometry().intersection(features[j].geometry()).asWkt()
                 for i,j in itertools.combinations(list, 2)
                 if features[i].geometry().intersects(features[j].geometry()) ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'polygon',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(intersections)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(intersections[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

By using shapefile with overlapped features of following image:

[image]

after running above code, I got following result:

[image]

However, these interceptions can also intercepts each other or with another primary features. In this case, for a complete clipping, you can use 'saga:polygonselfintersection' method from Processing in a very concise script as follow:

```
import processing

polys = QgsVectorLayer("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/overlapped_features.shp","self_intersections","ogr")
output = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/intersection.shp"
processing.runAndLoadResults("saga:polygonselfintersection", 
                {'POLYGONS':polys, 
                 'INTERSECT':output})
```

After running above code, result obtained was:

[image]

In attributes table was created a field (named ID) where it was placed all possible intersections for primary features.